# Not able to hit breakpoints inside src folders in vscode while debugging zest testcases

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, zest

Version:11.10.0
OS:Ubuntu
Scope:Debugging testcases
Module: Zest Test Framework
IDE:VSCode

I'm trying to debug my test cases. All breakpoints in spec.ts file works. but breakpoints in src/folders, ie, controller files never works. VSCode shows them as a unverified breakpoints.

launch.json:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Jest Tests",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
    "args": ["--runInBand","-i", "--config=${workspaceFolder}/jest.config.js"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "outFiles": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*"
    ],
    "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env"
    }
```

tsconfig.js:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
    "checkJs": false /* Report errors in .js files. */,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    },
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "src/test"],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "types": ["src/types"]
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfigFile: 'tsconfig.json'
        }
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'ts',
        'js'
    ],
    transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"],
    testMatch: [
        '**/*.spec.ts'
    ],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testResultsProcessor: "jest-sonar-reporter",
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [".*\\.d\\.ts"],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "src/**/**/*.{ts}",
    "!src/index.ts"
    ]
};
```

Comment: Can you add your `tsconfig.json` (or other build configuration) and `jest.config.js` to the question?

Comment: @ecraig12345 added both of them.

Comment: What happens if you add `"sourceMaps": true` to the launch configuration? Otherwise, this is different enough than configs I've used that I don't have any more suggestions.